# Getting error "p must be exactly 1024, 2048, 3072, or 4096 bits long" while creating ssh connection by using paramiko in python

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

I have written a python script to established SSH connection to NEs, which is working fine for multiple NEs. While testing I got error "p must be exactly 1024, 2048, 3072, or 4096 bits long" for few NEs(not for all NEs). I am not able to understand that why I am getting this error for few NEs. Please help to let me know or fix this issue. Please find below used paramiko version and code.

**Paramiko Version:**

```
Name: paramiko
Version: 2.9.2
Summary: SSH2 protocol library
Home-page: https://paramiko.org
Author: Jeff Forcier
Author-email: jeff@bitprophet.org
License: LGPL
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: bcrypt, cryptography, pynacl
Required-by: netmiko, scp
```

**CODE:**

```
TIMOUT = 2
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(TIMOUT * 3)
sock.connect((host, self.port))
transport = paramiko.Transport(sock)
transport.connect(username=self.username)
transport.auth_none(self.username)
channel = transport.open_channel(kind="session")
connected = True
print('connection true')
channel.get_pty()
channel.invoke_shell()
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am not able to edit and add print p value in dsa.py file due to permission issue. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl   Given solution is working fine, Thanks for your support